# How to get ping time of an IP address?

Tags: java, ip-address, ping, latency

I am a Mac user and use the ping command via Terminal to measure the ping time in ms. I wanted to create a Java app where I can simply enter the ip and get the ping response time.

I know that I can use `InetAddress` to determine whether the IP is reachable or not but how can I determine the ping time?

Comment: Fancy idea: call the `ping` command from your app! Or maybe have a look at the related questions (on the right)

Comment: "I know that I can use InetAddress to determine whether the IP is reachable or not" <-- no you can't. `InetAddress`' `.isReachable()` does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void ping (String entryIpAddress){
    try{    
         String command ="ping  "+entryIpAddress;
         Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
         process.getOutputStream();

    }catch(Exception e){}
}
```

Comment: after getting the Stream parse it to get the value you want